# Integral related to exponential function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, exponential-function, improper-integrals

I need a hint on how to attack the following integral.
$$\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-f(x)} \dfrac{\mathrm{d}^3 f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x^3} \,\mathrm{d}x.$$
I tried it by part and substitution, but I did not succeed. I know that the integral exists and that I can interchange derivative and integral and that $$\lim_{x\mapsto\infty} f(x) = 0.$$
Moreover $f(0)$ exists and $f \in C^{\infty}$.

Thanks a lot!

**My attempt:**
I tried to integrate by part twice where the function to derive is always $e^{-f(x)}$ and integrate the rest. My idea was to arrive at something similar to $e^{-f(x)}\, f(x)$ and then solve it easily by substitution. Unluckily, I arrived to evaluate
$$ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-f(x)} \left(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^3 \,\mathrm{d}x.$$
which still I'm not able to solve.

Comment: What were the results of your attempts at substitution and integration by parts?

Comment: Integration by parts seems to be the way to go. It seems like you've already provided yourself with a hint. Now if you show your solution and where you are stuck we will be able to offer a better advice

Comment: Thanks @Travis and and YuriY S. My attempt was to integrate by part twice where the function to derive is always $e^{-f(x)}$ and integrate the rest. The idea was to arrive to something similar to $$e^{-f(x)}\, \dfrac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}$$ and then solve easily by substitution. Unluckily, I arrived to evaluate $$\int_0^\infty e^{-f(x)} \left( \dfrac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^3 \mathrm{d}x$$ which still i'm not able to solve.